# Java Map, how to put UTF-8 string to the map correctly?

Tags: java, string, json, utf-8, dictionary

I have a Map, LinkedHashMap to be more exact.
And I want to put a string object to it.
And then I read this value to see what's actually stored.
The string itself has non-ascii characters (cyrillic, korean, etc).
Once I put it to the map and then read, these characters are replaced with ???s.
Some code:

```
Map obj = new LinkedHashMap();
System.out.println("name: " + getName());  // prints "i4niac_сим_sim"
obj.put("name", getName());
System.out.println("written stuff: " + obj.get("name"));  // prints i4niac_???_sim
```

What's the trick here?
I am using this map to make JSON object with json-simple and send it from server to client.

**Update:**

Ugh, sorry for all the mess.
First I blamed datastore, then map, finally, as expected, it was my fault in another place.
I was sending json data in app engine setting content type as "application/json"

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
// ...
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        resp.getWriter().println(jsonObj.toString());
}
```

It just never sent it as UTF-8, no matter which tricks I tried on backend side.
After changing to

```
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I finally received UTF-8 escape codes for non-ascii characters.

Comment: Do the terminal where you print the result display other UTF-8 strings properly? It could be a font issue...

Comment: Hi, you can see that I have completely changed the question.
The data is read correctly from datastore, my mistake overlooking it. The issue is with using Map, I put UTF-8 string there and get "ugly" one back.

Comment: Look into  the system properties for the encoding. I mean System.getProperty("file.encoding") (JVM) from the very same program.

Comment: Odd, I don't get that problem. I get the same string (`i4niac_сим_sim`) for both outputs.

Comment: On Java 6 and windows 7 in Eclipse I get the proper UTF-8 string, and on the console I get the expected ugly String... I'm curious what JRE/JDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

how do you know the characters are replaced with ??? -- is it not the case that your console is set to ASCII codepage or similar? Or is it not the case that the font you used in the console doesn't handle UTF-8 chars properly? Have you tried to write all of these to a file and open it in something like MS Word and verify if that's the case?

Comment: According to his code sample he's printing the value out before adding it to the map and it's displayed just fine at that point which disproves the console/font theory.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile your code with `-encoding` flag

like this

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 Test3.java
```

Answer (score 0):

> Java Map, how to put UTF-8 string to the map correctly?

Strings immutable and are always encoded as UTF-16. If you want to represent character data in any other encoding, you must use a byte array.

Since [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) doesn't mutate or serialize your string, the object value you put into it should be the one returned.

The only explanations I can think of:

- `getName()` doesn't return a reference to the same String every time (most likely)
- the `System.out` `PrintWriter` is modified concurrently
- the encoding of the console receiving the data is modified concurrently

You can emit the hexadecimal form of the String to ensure display bugs aren't the problem:

```
public static String toCodeUnits(String s) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(char codeUnit : s.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append(String.format("%04x ", (int) codeUnit));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

For `i4niac_сим_sim`, this code will return:

```
"0069 0034 006e 0069 0061 0063 005f 0441 0438 043c 005f 0073 0069 006d "
```